# How does importing a content type work?

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

I have used featured to create  a yml file for views and other configurations.  When I import my yml file all that is created is a content type that has a title.  Is there a way to import the fields with the content type?

```
uuid: 1bd0f08e-cf80-4fc3-8707-7a9d19c404da
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - menu_ui
third_party_settings:
  menu_ui:
    available_menus:
      - main
    parent: 'main:'
name: Podcast
type: podcast
description: 'Allows Drupal to play an audio file.  The Embed Podcast field should contain the name of the Podcast exactly as it is uploaded to Drupal.'
help: ''
new_revision: false
preview_mode: 1
display_submitted: true
```

this is my file and there is nothing about the fields in a content type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a field to custom content type you need

1. **field.field.node.content-type.field-name.yml**
2. **field.storage.node.field-name.yml**

The easiest way for you is create the content type and fields via UI and then just simply export it in `admin/config/development/configuration/single/export` (you have to install the config core module). Then remove  **uuid** and you are done.

While exporting, export following configuration types..

- Content Type
- Entity form display
- Entity view display
- Field
- Field Storage

Hope this will help you.

Comment: quick question. is this possible if i put it in a module?  I tired to put it in a module and put all the files in module/config/install  but my module wont stay installed.  am i missing a file or is that the wrong way to do this?

Comment: you can do it by placeing all **.yml** files in **module/config/install** folder. It worked for me.

Comment: I will check for misspellings or something then. The when i try to install the module it wont install.  no errors show up or anything it just doesnt install

Comment: In modules page it showing as enabled..??

Comment: no. when i click the enable the page reloads and the module shows up as not enabled

Comment: i think its related to module code ..

Comment: like just some code or in the .module file specifically?

Comment: May be, or sometimes this will happen when we trying to install same module with same fields and content type repeatedly, because the fields or content type  will insert to db in first time. if we try again causes duplication of fields in db.